# Login and registration form

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<style>
    label{
        width:100px;
        float:left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login_form">
<form action="login.php" method="post" >
    <p>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" size="30"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
echo $count;

    session_start();
    include('configdb.php');
    mysql_select_db("upload_site2", $con);

// username and password sent from form 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$email = stripslashes($email);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email' and password='$pass'");
$result=mysql_query($sql2);
echo $email;
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("email");
session_register("password"); 
header("location:member.php");
}
else{echo'wrong';}


?>                                        

</body>
</html>
```

when i open the page of this code ,it directly shows me the echo (wrong) on the screen before i even write the email and pass .also when i enter the email and pass its not redirected to "member.php" but it stays on the same page...thnx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem of it trying to login before you submit the form you need to wrap the login code in an if statement, which will determine if the form was submitted.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // now do the login code
}
```

The second problem of it not redirecting is probably due to your echo's which happen before the redirect. You can't echo or print anything before a redirect. So remove all of those echo $count and echo $email etc.

Also check your error log or turn on error reporting for further details. Finally, use mysql_error() to debug a query if you think it's not working.

Turn on error reporting (at the very top of the script):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Another problem you have is this code:

```
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email' and password='$pass'");
$result=mysql_query($sql2);
```

Change it to

```
$sql2 ="SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email' and password='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql2);

if(!$result)
{
    die('error: ' . mysql_error()); // remove this after you have finished debugging
}
```

Comment: i tried all those but still same problemm..its not giving me any errors

Comment: Show the new code after you have added the post check and removed the echo's.

Comment: ive putt he code but on a diff quest plz see it overthere..and thank you so muchhh

Comment: I've edited the answer with another problem you need to address. Also, turn on error reporting as I have shown. Edit your original question with the updated code.

Comment: thnx it worked with me..i didnt realize the mistake at first:):D:D..thnx for ur time

Comment: anyway..now when i login with as dif email than paso@hotmail.com it wither tells me hello paso and not the other name..or it gives me the same error back..do u have an idea what might be the reason??

Comment: Show the code that is doing the hello message, is that in member.php?

Comment: yes it is..it is working for 2 emails.when i press submit,it takes me to memeber.php and it says hi passo even if it was my email or the other one.when i put the other emails found on the database i remain in the login.php

Comment: There must be a problem with the code in member.php, show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `header("location:member.php");` if headers already sent. Headers sent because you have html characters before your `header` function, and not only `header`, `session_register` have same problem too.

Try:

```
<?php

session_start();
include('configdb.php');
mysql_select_db("upload_site2", $con);

// username and password sent from form 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$email = stripslashes($email);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email' and password='$pass'");
$result=mysql_query($sql2);
echo $email;
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("email");
session_register("password"); 
header("location:member.php");
}
else{if(!empty($email))$answer='wrong';}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<style>
    label{
        width:100px;
        float:left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login_form">
<form action="login.php" method="post" >
    <p>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" size="30"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
<?=$answer?>                                     

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still its not redirected to the second page::S:S

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` before `session_start();` and check maybe you have some other errors.

Comment: Er doesn't it need to be `header('Location: member.php');`

Comment: i dont understand wat u mean:S

Answer (score 0):

Add `exit();` after redirecting the page.

Comment: is it getting inside if($count==1) condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
header('Location: index.php');

}
 echo $_SESSION['email'];

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Secured Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is secured page with session: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></b>
<br>You can put your restricted information here.</p>
<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>


<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
    </form>
    <p>
        <a href="list_files.php">See all files</a>
    </p>




</body>
</html>
```

this is the member.php